# matplotlib: manually (interactively) picked contour label adds extra lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am finding that manually picking contour labels in matplotlib adds extra lines to the plot.  In addition, the contour label is rotated from the local tangent to the contour line.  For example, the following code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Define surface
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

#Plot surface
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)

#Manually pick labels
CS.clabel(CS.levels, manual = True, inline = True)
```

with some mouse clicks on the contour lines, results in this plot:
[image: test]

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Perhaps this is an axes transformation bug…

In case it matters, I am running matplotlib 1.3.0 and python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2475) and there is a fix ([PR #2843](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2843)).  This will be fixed in the 1.4 release.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the post, and, more importantly, thank you for fixing the bug.  Google doesn't seem to place github issue reports very high on it's search results list, if at all.  I will need to search github explicitly from now on.

Comment: I would point out it is not merged or released yet, so I would not call it 'fixed' (yet).

Comment: almost 10 years later, and it seems that this is still an issue in matplotlib 3.8.0. Unfortunately the OPs image is no longer available, but the description of the issue sounds just like what I'm seeing. When I manually add contours, random contour lines are added over my figure , and the labels are not rotated correctly. @Stretch do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @pretzlstyle, I resurrected my original example with matplotlib 3.7.0 and the interactively picked labels worked fine.  I am not sure why you are having trouble.