# Labelling contours manually via clabel adds spurious new lines to the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I have a set of contours made with `plt.contourf`. I am now trying to label the contours with `plt.clabel` with `manual=True`. This opens the plot, and prompts me to click on the figure to add labels. When I do this, new spurious contours are added to the plot, which are not correct given the data. Some labels are drawn correctly, but most are not.

I came across [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901365/matplotlib-manually-interactively-picked-contour-label-adds-extra-lines) which seems to be describing the same issue, though an answer there claims that this was identified as a bug and fixed years ago. Has anyone run into this?

Before clicking:

[image]

After a few clicks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apologies that my question does not have a minimal working example; when trying to write, one, I found that I could no reproduce the problem on one machine, but I could on another, with identical code. After some sleuthing, my conclusion was:

This bug was not present in version `3.6` of matplotlib. Sometime after this, it must have been re-introduced. It was not fixed again until matplotlib version `3.8.2`. See the [changelog](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/github_stats.html) for this version here, and the associated pull request [PR#27334](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/27334/). Update to at least this version to fix the problem.